# Query Optimizing Request

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very sorry if this question is structured in not a very helpful manner or the question itself is not a very good one!

I need to `update` a `MSSQL` `table` call `component` every 10 minutes based on information from another `table` call `materials_progress`

I have nearly 60000 records in `component` and more than 10000 records in `materials_progress`

I wrote an `update query` to do the job, but it takes longer than 4 minutes to complete execution!
Here is the `query` :

```
UPDATE component 
SET stage_id = 
CASE 
    WHEN t.required_quantity <= t.total_received THEN 27
    WHEN t.total_ordered < t.total_received THEN 18
    ELSE 18
END
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        mp.job_id,  
        mp.line_no,  
        mp.component,  
        l.quantity AS line_quantity, 
        CASE WHEN mp.component_name_id = 2 THEN l.quantity*2
            ELSE l.quantity
        END AS required_quantity,
        SUM(ordered) AS total_ordered, SUM(received) AS total_received ,
        c.component_id 
    FROM line l 
    LEFT JOIN component c ON c.line_id = l.line_id
    LEFT JOIN materials_progress mp ON l.job_id = mp.job_id AND l.line_no = mp.line_no AND c.component_name_id = mp.component_name_id 
    WHERE 
        mp.job_id IS NOT NULL  
        AND (mp.cancelled IS NULL OR mp.cancelled = 0)
        AND (mp.manual_override IS NULL OR mp.manual_override = 0)
        AND c.stage_id = 18
    GROUP BY  mp.job_id,  mp.line_no,  mp.component, l.quantity, mp.component_name_id, component_id
    ) AS t

WHERE 
    component.component_id = t.component_id
```

I am not going to explain the scenario as it too complex.. could somebody please please tell me what makes this query this much expensive and a way to get around it?

Thank you very very much in advance!!!

Edit 1:
Here is the execution plan;
[image]

Comment: Indexing the fields individually won't help as much as creating an index whose key is all three fields, or whose key and covering columns cover the three fields.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure your logic behind those joins but some part of the query can be optimised as; (for ex; `WHEN t.total_ordered < t.total_received THEN 18` of your first `CASE` does not make sense at all as `ELSE part is also equal to`18`)

**EDIT:** Sub query brought back in with some optimisations. Syntax looks alright now.

```
UPDATE c2 SET stage_id = 
         CASE 
           WHEN t.required_quantity  <= t.total_received THEN 27
         --WHEN t.total_ordered < t.total_received THEN 18 (NOT NEED THIS BIT)
           ELSE 18
         END


FROM component c2 INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT c.component_id,
            CASE mp.component_name_id WHEN 2 THEN l.quantity*2
                 ELSE l.quantity
            END AS required_quantity,
            SUM(received) AS total_received,
                    --(NOT NEED THIS BIT AND OTHER LIST OF COLUMNS)
                    --SUM(ordered) AS total_ordered
     FROM line l 
        LEFT JOIN component c ON c.line_id = l.line_id
        LEFT JOIN materials_progress mp ON l.job_id = mp.job_id AND 
              l.line_no = mp.line_no AND c.component_name_id = 
                                                   mp.component_name_id 
     WHERE 
            mp.job_id IS NOT NULL  
            AND (ISNULL(mp.cancelled,0) = 0) --(OR CONDITION REMOVED)
            AND (ISNULL(mp.manual_override,0) = 0) --(OR CONDITION REMOVED)
            AND c.stage_id = 18
     GROUP BY  mp.job_id,  mp.line_no,  mp.component, 
                l.quantity, mp.component_name_id, component_id) AS t

ON c2.component_id = t.component_id --(INNER JOIN)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are `join`s used in the `query`. Also, too many conditions put in `WHERE` Clause.
You can create `Index`es as per `query execution plan`.

Refer: [Execution Plan](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/graphical-execution-plans-for-simple-sql-queries/)

**EDIT:** 
Following Indexes might be helpful:

INDEX on component_id column of component table
INDEX ON job_id, line_no, component_name_id column of materials_progress table

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not any major problem with your query . you need to remove some unused columns from group by close . I can see there are mp.job_id,  mp.line_no,  mp.component, l.quantity, mp.component_name_id, component_id columns in group by close . Group by close take lot of time to execute. you need to calculate sum directly in core query then join it with outer query it will definitely solve your problem . I dot know the table structure of your query if you provide me a schema then I can help you more. Thanks